# Highcharts mouse over point different label text

Tags: highcharts, mouseover, label

I need that text from xAxis and label displayed on mouse over point to be different.
[image]

All labels for xAxis ( circled with blue ) I have in array but they are used by default for label on mouse over ( circled with red ), I need to change data for all labels display on mouse over ( label circled with red ).

Comment: try tooltip->formatter;function(){}

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Comment: I tried to use tooltip formater, when I try to write return this.value.substr(0,40);, charts is not designed and some letters are visible in right top corner.

Comment: have you any live demo?